# Get specific user permissions on Azure Data Lake Gen2 (ACL)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-lake

I am working with Azure Functions, and I would like to know how I can see the permissions of a user for a certain directory or file.

To get the info of ACL I am following the next documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python (For the conexion I have used **Connect by using an account key** option)

I am able to get the next information:

```
{
    'accept_ranges': None,
    'cache_control': None,
    'content_disposition': None,
    'content_encoding': None,
    'content_language': None,
    'content_length': None,
    'content_range': None,
    'content_type': None,
    'content_md5': None,
    'date': datetime.datetime(XXXXX),
    'etag': '"4545454545"',
    'last_modified': datetime.datetime(XXXXX),
    'request_id': 'XXXXX',
    'version': '2019-02-02',
    'resource_type': None,
    'properties': None,
    'owner': '123',
    'group': '123',
    'permissions': 'rwxr-x---',
    'acl': 'user: : rwx,
    group: : r-x,
    other: : ---',
    'lease_duration': None,
    'lease_state': None,
    'lease_status': None,
    'error_code': None
}
```

This returns generic information, but what I would like to know is how can I get permission information for a specific user. I know how can I get user id or thr user's group id, but not how to relate to ACL.

Maybe I need to use an API?

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your result, you haven't given permissions to a user.

So you need follow this screenshot to give the permissions.

[image]

Then you could use the code to get its ACL.

```
acl_props = directory_client.get_access_control()

print(acl_props['acl'])
```

It should be like this:

```
user::rwx,
user:256xxxx6-019b-479c-a71f-d5axxxx93143:r-x,
group::r-x,
mask::r-x,
other::---
```

We can find that the second line is the ACL for the user allenwu1.

Then you could use `str.index('user:{user id}:')` to get its position. Then you can get the next three characters, which is the user's ACL.

Comment: Thanks for the response Allen! My doubt now, is how can I know if that user have permissions if I check in a folder inside that directory? If I do the same process, I shouldn't get that permission. Is there any way to do this? Cheers

Comment: @jmarco10  Just use `str.index('user:{user id}:')`. The `user id` here is the user id you want to know if it has the permission. If it doesn't have permissions for this directory, `str.index('user:{user id}:')` will return `-1`.

Comment: Not sure if we are on the same page... For example: I set permissions to a user in the folder A, inside the folder A, we have folders B and C. If we get the ACL of the folders B or C, I am not getting back any user, but it should have permission because the user have permission for the parent folder. Do I explained myself correctly?

Comment: @jmarco10 Sorry for having a misunderstanding. You need to select Default ACLs on the parent folder. After that, if you create a child folder in it, the user will have the permission on the child folder. This setting will not affect existing subfolders. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#types-of-access-control-lists. And you can select Default ACLs like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I76Xc.png

Comment: Thank you very much Allen, really well explained :)

Comment: Hi, my problem is somewhat opposite to this. Could you please let me know how to Set specific user permissions on Azure Data Lake Gen2 (ACL) using Python script. I want to set different permissions for different group of users, is that possible using python?